# What could cause a git commit outside a branch?

Tags: git, github

After making a commit, I have found that sometimes, the commit falls in an  automatically created branch, with a name as a hash (i.e. "48918c").

In the next commit, git offers me to keep my changes creating a branch (as a last chance to keep them).

This always happens to me in a particular linux box, and cannot detect why.

Comment: What is the complete error message>

Comment: What is the output of `git branch -l`

Comment: I can't tell you right now. Will wait to another occurrence of the issue. I workarounded it making a git branch and ensuring myself that I am checked out over the correct branch, previously to each commit. It is weird.